# How to do an ajax request in rails between a view and a controller belonging to a different scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, action

My problem is this, I'm implementing as homework a sort of web site like *stackoverflow* of questions and answers and what I want to do is to make an ajax request when a user fills a form to create answer **inside the view 'show' of a current question** to update this view without having to load again the entire view.
I already know how to make ajax request works when the action and the view belong to the same controller, but in this case the answer is going to be save in a different scaffold, so I don't know how to chain the results of calling the action in the Answers controller to the action that show the view in the Questions controller, neither what *.js.erb* should I create:
for the action 'show' in Questions controller, or
for the action 'create' in  Answers controller

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

As your save answer goes to create action of answer controller then you should have a create.js.erb with sort of the following code:

answers/create.js.erb

```
$('#answers').append('<%= escape_javascript("#{render :partial => 'answers/details', :locals => {answer: @answer}}".html_safe)%>');
```

provided that you have `answers/_detail.html.erb` partial to render answer detail.

Comment: Didn't work to me. I edited the question because I think I wasn't clear enough. But what you post me is the situation I already know how to handle.